# Install error easy_install python

Tags: python, windows, easy-install

I use Windows 7 and Python IDLE.

I'm trying to use easy_install but gut this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       easy_install NameError: name 'easy_install' is not defined

In included in my 'Path' the directory where it has been installed (C:\Python27\Scripts).
Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Maybe...
In Python IDLE > File > Path browser, I cannot see C:\Python27\Scripts. How to add it ?

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to install Pip via Chocolatey. I have installed Python. Choco says 'python v3.7.4 already installed'. But, choco won't recognise Python's existence.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure  you've done all of this.

- [Adding Python to Windows Path.](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html)
- Downloading and installing [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) for appropriate python version.
- Adding Scripts directory (for instance C:\Python27\Scripts) to Windows Path.
  You can check installing by opening a command prompt and typing "`easy_install`"

Comment: I try to run the following command in the command prompt sous windows: "easy_install" , but the windows open and shut up quickly and nothing happen. Any suggestion ?

Comment: have you checked your Path using Windows Environment Variables?  it sounds like your path is malformed, I would suggest cleaning it out.

Answer (score 2):

`easy_install` is an executable program, not a Python script. Run it from the Windows command line, not from Python.

Comment: I try to run the following command in Executer sous windows: "easy_install -U Scrapy" , but the windows open and shut up quickly and nothing is installed. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Run it from the command line (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: A black windows opened and shut up quickly and nothing is installed.

Comment: The command line can be opened by typing Windows+R, `cmd`, Enter. In the resulting window, type your command.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem when I was trying to use easy_install. I finally was able to install both easy_install and pip although I really needed just one of them to get the job done.

If you are still struggling with this problem, I would suggest you follow these instructions I put together recently for others who asked me to. It is fairly easy to follow in order to re-install easy_install on your machine. I also explain how to add the directory to your path - which sounds like you have done already but still seeing the above problem. Here is the link that might help you solve this problem.

[Simple easy_install installation guide for windows](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-install-easy_install/)

I hope this helps you get back up and running again! Good luck!